# ThreeJS does not update scene after children update

Tags: javascript, threejs-editor

I am woking on: [ThreeJS Editor](https://threejs.org/editor/). And I want to force update scene after I change `children` props in the `scene` 
Now I have some `Box`(get by `Scene`) and I want to add some `SphereGeometry` to this Box:

```
buildSceneGeometry() {
   const objects = this.scene.children;
   // Generate connecting points
   const connectionPoints = [
     { x: -0.5, y: 0, z: 0 },
     { x: 0.5, y: 0, z: 0 },
     { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0.25 },
   ]
   objects.forEach((data: any) => {
     connectionPoints.forEach((point) => {
       const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1)
       const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: '#ff0000' })
       const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial)
       sphere.name = NAME_SNAP
       sphere.position.set(point.x, point.y, point.z)
       data.children = [...data.children, sphere]
     })
   })
   // force update scene here...

}
```

My expected: [image: My expected]

But, after I run `buildSceneGeometry`, it likes: [image]

After refreshing by `F5` press. It's working, but I want to force update it. 
And, I'm using [three](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three) npm: `^0.158.0`, 
Thank all